Socket Hang Up issue in Vue Storefront with Magento backend
We have encountered the following error on our website, https://mpex-2gqq4.ondigitalocean.app, which is a Vue.js (Vue storefront) website using Magento as the backend. The website calls APIs using GraphQL to 5bc36db30a.nxcli.io. It seems to occur when users continuously navigate between pages. To replicate this error, please navigate between pages without interruption.
{
    "name": "ApolloError",
    "graphQLErrors": [],
    "protocolErrors": [],
    "clientErrors": [],
    "networkError": {
        "message": "request to https://5bc36db30a.nxcli.io/graphql?query=query+categoryMeta%28%24filters%3ACategoryFilterInput%29%7Bcategories%28filters%3A%24filters%29%7Bitems%7Bmeta_title+meta_description+meta_keywords+name+__typename%7D__typename%7D%7D&operationName=categoryMeta&variables=%7B%22filters%22%3A%7B%22category_uid%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D failed, reason: socket hang up",
        "type": "system",
        "errno": "ECONNRESET",
        "code": "ECONNRESET"
    },
    "message": "request to https://5bc36db30a.nxcli.io/graphql?query=query+categoryMeta%28%24filters%3ACategoryFilterInput%29%7Bcategories%28filters%3A%24filters%29%7Bitems%7Bmeta_title+meta_description+meta_keywords+name+__typename%7D__typename%7D%7D&operationName=categoryMeta&variables=%7B%22filters%22%3A%7B%22category_uid%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D failed, reason: socket hang up"
}

We utilize Vue Storefront for the frontend and Magento for the backend.
Checked network configurations for any potential issues.
Reviewed server logs for any relevant errors or warnings. Nothing found.

Do you have a GraphQL subscription in there? Or some tracking of some sort (Hotjar etc)? Maybe the Apollo devtools have some insight? This is quite a popular issue on the Web apparently. I found this one but depending on how you use Apollo in your app, you might find something even more narrow and relevant to use. The team from Alokai (Vue storefront) might also help more specifically on that one, consider joining their discord to have more precise help from them. Assuming this is not coming from Magento of course.

Might also be a bug in the Service workers maybe? Considering upgrading towards Nuxt3 and not using bloated jQuery-based solutions like owl-carousel. PS: LOTS of tracking happening on the website indeed. Overall, I'd say that this error is not that much of a big deal considering everything that happens on the website in general. I wasn't able to see the bug after 10 pages of navigation, so it might also be a state issue with something triggering the error on some specific pages? Overall, the website is still doing fine with that kind of error. Not the priority I'd dare to say.

@kissu This issue is a priority for us, especially since we are planning to go live soon. If this issue occurs during the live launch, it could have serious consequences. Additionally, it's not limited to specific pages; it occurs randomly on all pages. Based on our observations, we suspect it might be a timeout issue originating from Vue Storefront, as there are no errors logged on the Magento side. It's worth noting that this issue persists even on our local server.
